# need help regarding the following regular expression

Tags: python, regex

i am using python with re module for regular expressions
i want to remove all the characters from the string except numbers and characters.
To achieve this i am using sub function

Code Snippet:-

```
>>> text="foo.bar"

>>> re.sub("[^A-Z][^a-z]","",text)
```

'fobar'

I wanted to know why above expression removes the "o."?

I am not able to understand why it removes the "o"
Can someone please explain me what is going on behind this?

I know to correct solution of this problem is

```
>>> re.sub("[^A-Z ^a-z]","",text)
```

'foobar'

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `o` matches `[^A-Z]` and `.` matches `[^a-z]`.

And the correct solution is `[^A-Za-z0-9]`.

Comment: If you believe that this answer solves your problem, you can accept it by clicking the validation sign on its left :)

Answer (score 3):

A very important aspect to realize is that `[^A-Z][^a-z]` represents **two** characters (one for each character group), while `[^A-Za-z]` represents only one.

Answer (score 2):

### Explained in detail:

The `[^A-Z]` means all characters except uppercase A to Z, the second `o` in `foo.bar` is not uppercase so it matches as a matter of fact everything in foo.bar is matched at this point.

Then you add `[^a-z]` so you look for a character that is not lowercase, only the dot matches.

Combine both and you look for a non-uppercase character followed by a non-lowercase character so this matches `o.`

The solution is the one proposed by Ignacio.